# How can I set an specific Icon on a Marker in Xamarin GoogleMaps

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-maps-markers

I would create an Android App where I can show geo data and other things. 
I implement Android.Gms.Maps and would change the default ping icon of a marker into an dot.

I tried different ways but nothing worked for me...please help me!

**attempt 1: (Open the bmp icon from path)**

```
_myPositionMarker = _map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .SetPosition(new LatLng(34.8094, 12.7484))
        .SetTitle("Actual Position")
        .SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromPath("C:\\Users\\my.name\\source\\repos\\repo\\appName\\Resources\\drawable\\dot.bmp")));
```

*error message: failed to decode image, must be a bitmap*

**attempt 2: (I have included the bmp file as embedded resource)**

```
_myPositionMarker = _map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .SetPosition(new LatLng(34.8094, 12.7484))
        .SetTitle("Actual Position")
        .SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.dot)));
```

*error message: the app did'nt compile but no failure is shown*

**attempt 3: (also as resource)**

```
var markerImg = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.dot);

_myPositionMarker = _map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .SetPosition(new LatLng(34.8094, 12.7484))
       .SetTitle("Actual Position")
       .SetIcon(markerImg));
```

*error message: the app did'nt compile but no failure is shown*

***nothing worked! I have no idea to solve the problem :-/***

*to be sure...*

```
_myPositionMarker = _map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .SetPosition(new LatLng(24.8094, 12.7484))
        .SetTitle("Actual Position")
```

*...shows the default marker correctly and the app work well*

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 1 won't work as the path does not point at a path on the device itself.

Attempt 2 and 3 should work as long as the Drawable is not a VectorDrawable or XML based drawable. It needs to be an jpg or png.
These also can't be embedded resources, but have to be Android Resources, so they need to be in the appropriate Resources folder and Build Action set to `AndroidResource`.

Also make sure to add markers after the map ready callback has been called.

Comment: Thanks, with changing embedded to android source it work's